# SQL Performing a inner join but need to have different query based on certain values

Tags: mysql, sql

I'll try and explain this as best I can, I don't really know if i'm going to do a good job. 
I need to perform an INNER JOIN. I have a bunch of "AND" checks, like this:

```
INNER JOIN lineItem cli ON acty.organization_id = cli.organization_id
AND acty.wkstn_id = cli.wkstn_id
AND acty.loc_id = cli.loc_id
```

But when It comes to a certain value, if it is equal to a certain value, I want to perform another check.

Basically like this (pseudo code)

```
If
acty.item_status = 'MODIFIED'
```

Add the following line to the list of "AND's"

```
AND acty.trans_seq = 1

If 
    acty.item_status != 'MODIFIED'
```

Then Add the following line to the list of "AND's"

```
AND acty.trans_seq = 2
```

How would I do this in a SQL query?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using boolean logic:

```
INNER JOIN lineItem cli
ON acty.organization_id = cli.organization_id AND
   acty.wkstn_id = cli.wkstn_id AND
   acty.loc_id = cli.loc_id AND
   ((acty.item_status = 'MODIFIED' AND acty.trans_seq = 1) OR
    (acty.item_status <> 'MODIFIED' AND acty.trans_seq = 2)
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

This logic

```
If acty.item_status = 'MODIFIED'
Add the following line to the list of "AND's" 
AND acty.trans_seq = 1
```

you can change to

```
(acty.item_status = 'MODIFIED' AND acty.trans_seq = 1)
```

and this

```
acty.item_status != 'MODIFIED'
Then Add the following line to the list of "AND's" 
AND acty.trans_seq = 2
```

you can change to

```
 ( acty.item_status <> 'MODIFIED' AND acty.trans_seq = 2)
```

both expressions you can join using `OR` operator - because only one of the condition can be true.
Full code should be like this:

```
INNER JOIN lineItem cli ON acty.organization_id = cli.organization_id
AND acty.wkstn_id = cli.wkstn_id
AND acty.loc_id = cli.loc_id
AND ((acty.item_status = 'MODIFIED' AND acty.trans_seq = 1) 
     OR ( acty.item_status <> 'MODIFIED' AND acty.trans_seq = 2))
```